# lambda retry failing on s3_client.head_object()

Tags: python, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, boto3

My lambda function is failing simply because I'm still writing it and I haven't put  any code to catch errors just yet...

However I noticed that on the retries, it's not running the same as the first invocation, it seems to have lost access to some data.

I'm using `response = s3_client.head_object(Bucket=bucket, Key=key)` to get access to the metadata as suggested by [Accessing Meta Data from AWS S3 with AWS Lambda](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35744029/accessing-meta-data-from-aws-s3-with-aws-lambda).

On the first invocation, `s3_client.head_object(...)` returns exactly what I need.  However when the function fails, and the second invocation runs, I get a new error:

```
[ERROR] ClientError: An error occurred (404) when calling the HeadObject operation: Not Found
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/var/task/CreateThumbnail.py", line 25, in handler
    response = s3_client.head_object(Bucket=bucket, Key=key)
  File "/var/task/botocore/client.py", line 357, in _api_call
    return self._make_api_call(operation_name, kwargs)
  File "/var/task/botocore/client.py", line 661, in _make_api_call
    raise error_class(parsed_response, operation_name)
```

Why would the successive invocations lose access to this?  I've verified that I'm still getting the same response for `event` and therefore `bucket` and `key` etc.

Bonus: Is there another way to get at the metadata?

EDIT 1:  This lambda function is called via an S3 POST Trigger...
EDIT 2:  This actually only seems to error out maybe 50% of the time, the more files that are dropped into S3, the more it errors. Almost like there's a caching error?

```
import boto3
import os
import sys
import uuid
from PIL import Image
import PIL.Image

s3_client = boto3.client('s3')
logger = logging.getLogger()
logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)

def resize_image(image_path, resized_path):
    with Image.open(image_path) as image:
        image.thumbnail(tuple(x / 2 for x in image.size))
        image.save(resized_path)

def handler(event, context):
    logger.info(event)
    for record in event['Records']:
        bucket = record['s3']['bucket']['name']
        key = record['s3']['object']['key']

        response = s3_client.head_object(Bucket=bucket, Key=key)
        logger.info('Response: {}'.format(response))

        download_path = '/tmp/{}{}'.format(uuid.uuid4(), key)
        upload_path = '/tmp/resized-{}'.format(key)

        s3_client.download_file(bucket, key, download_path)
        resize_image(download_path, upload_path)
        s3_client.upload_file(upload_path, '{}resized'.format(bucket), key)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out I was uploading some files with a bracket `[` in the name...

According to https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/UsingMetadata.html under "Characters to Avoid" this is not advised.

Thanks to [What are valid S3 key names that can be accessed via the S3 rest API?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7116450/what-are-valid-s3-key-names-that-can-be-accessed-via-the-s3-rest-api/11303117) for pointing me to this resource.